# I would like to calculate z-scores based on two factors, is there a way to do this?

Tags: r, tapply

I would like to calculate the z scores of a summed scale based on two factors: Gender, and Age group (four factors).

How can I do that in R? I'm really new to R, and only started learning, I came across

```
tapply(AgingData$StandMen, list(AgingData$AgeGroups, AgingData$Gender_2),
      FUN= "scale")
```

But the result is not a data frame. How can I turn it into a data frame? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be better if you provide a reproducible example and you show the expected output. That's said, the result of `tapply`

```
res <- tapply(AgingData$StandMen, list(AgingData$AgeGroups, AgingData$Gender_2),
      FUN= "scale")
```

is an array with dimensions:

```
nelevls(AgingData$AgeGroups) x nlevles(AgingData$Gender_2)
```

Here you can convert it to a data.frame using

```
as.data.frame(res)
```

But I doubt is that what you are looking for, I guess you want to get the result in the long format either:

You use reshape2 package to transform the  result  :

```
library(reshape2)
melt(res)
```

Or you use , you don't use `tapply`, and you try `ddply` from `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(AgingData,.(AgeGroups,Gender_2),transform,scale)
```